# When does "second annihilator" of a (principal) ideal equal the ideal itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose that $R$ is a (local) ring and $r\in R$. When do the equations $\operatorname{Ann}_R(\operatorname{Ann}_R(r))=Rr$ or $\sqrt{\operatorname{Ann}_R(\operatorname{Ann}_R(r))}=\sqrt{Rr}$ hold?

I already know that it holds for Artinian Gorenstein rings (due to an exercise in Bruns-Herzog) and it seems to be true for $R=\Bbb {Z}/n\Bbb {Z}$.
The question is more interesting when we also assume that $\operatorname{Ann}_R(r)\in \operatorname{Ass}(R)$.

Comment: It's interesting: double application of the annihilator is a form of closure, and the radical of an ideal is a form of closure. Since I do not think about radicals of ideals in general, I have no idea how they interact with annihilators. So: I will be very interested in seeing more about this question!

Comment: Reposted [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/129949/when-does-second-annihilator-of-a-principal-ideal-equal-the-ideal-itself-ie).

Answer (score 1):

I'm addressing the title question. $l(X)$ denotes a left annihilator, $r(X)$ denotes a right annihilator.

A ring is called *right P-injective* if $l(r(a))=Ra$ for all $a\in R$. You can find this condition discussed in detail in Nicholson and Yousif's [*Quasi-Frobenius rings*](http://books.google.com/books?id=yHke_PLh8gsC&pg=PA96&dq=P+injective+ring&hl=en&sa=X&ei=z2CKUef2Hsq9yQGWhoBw&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=P%20injective%20ring&f=false) on page 96.

As the name kind of suggests, right self-injective rings are also right P-injective. Since $\Bbb Z/(n)$ is quasi-Frobenius (hence self-injective) for every $n\ge2$, that is why it holds in your example. For commutative local rings, quasi-Frobenius rings are exactly the zero-dimensional Gorenstein rings.

Every von-Neumann regular ring (doesn't have to be commutative) is left and right P-injective, so that gives a really broad class of (non-Noetherian) examples as well.